# Create named pipe in Ruby

Tags: ruby, named-pipes, mkfifo

I am trying to create a named pipe inside Ruby. Besides using the `system` command (`system("mkfifo #{pipe_name}")`), is there a native Ruby function allowing me to do this?

Comment: Is there any benefit to a Ruby function over using the system command?

Answer (score 10):

Current versions of Ruby (starting with 2.3.0) now have a native [File::mkfifo](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/File.html#method-c-mkfifo):

```
File.mkfifo('pipe_name')
```

---

**Old answer for older versions of Ruby:**

I don't believe there's anything fully native, but there's the [mkfifo gem](https://github.com/shurizzle/ruby-mkfifo).

Install like this:

```
gem install mkfifo
```

Then use like this:

```
require "mkfifo"
File.mkfifo('pipe_name')
```

Comment: There also seems to exist an all-in-one solution https://github.com/shurizzle/ruby-fifo

Comment: If you look closely, these two gems are from the same author. "mkfifo" was created 11 months ago while "ruby-fifo" was created 3 years ago but I am not sure which one is better. mkfifo bundles fifo into the File class so one might use a fifo just as a regular file.

Comment: As I see, ruby-fifo depends on ruby-mkfifo.

Comment: A native [File::mkfifo](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/File.html#method-c-mkfifo) was introduced in Ruby 2.3.0.

Comment: @Steve Thanks for letting me know—I've updated my answer.

Comment: The native method isn't implemented on Windows. github.com/shurizzle/ruby-fifo says it's cross-platform.